# AngularJs: Set Text to a Text Box by Click On That Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to send a text to a textbox on that "Text 1" Click

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<td ng-show="table.similarParts">
   <input ng-hide="item.is_new == false" type="text" class="form-control" uib-tooltip="You Can Filter Different Part Also" uib-tooltip-trigger="focus" uib-tooltip-placement="top"/>
</td>
<td class="wd-80" ng-show="table.similarParts">
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown="dropdown" ng-hide="item.is_new == false">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" uib-tooltip="Search This Part From Available Parts"" uib-tooltip-trigger="focus" uib-tooltip-placement="top"> <em class="fa fa-search"></em></button>
     <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" type="button" uib-dropdown-toggle="">
       <span class="caret"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">default</span>
     </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a>Text 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a>Text 2</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </td>
```

And Here is the Output:

[image]

I want to send this `Text 1` to a TextBox Input on that "Text 1" Click ("Button is that magnifier glass")

Comment: javascript lets you use `.value = "Text 1"` to set the value of an input. However, if you're using an angular controlled input, you should be able to set its value from within your controller by setting `bom_item.part = "Text 1"`

Comment: it is not always "Text 1"

Comment: pass the value you want to set to a function that sets it into the input value. You should be able to bind the click event of any of the list items in your dropdown

Comment: I m new to angular js can you please give me an example it would be a great help

Comment: Have a look at the example under [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) that should be able to point you in the direction of binding functions and setting values :)

Comment: I Edit My Question please  look at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this :

Bind both select and input to the same `ngModel`:

**Note: Given the logic here. CSS and other dropdown related changes i didn't make.**
In controller:

On click of `li` ,the text value will be displayed in input text box.

```js
    angular.module('app', []).controller('dummy', function($scope) {
              $scope.call= function(event){
              $scope.valueText = angular.element(event.target).text();
              }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="dummy">
      <input type="text" ng-model="valueText" />
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-click="call($event)">
         <li><a>Text 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a>Text 2</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
     
     
    </div>
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: look at my code once i m not using <select> dropdown

Comment: @UrvashiBhatt,Logic i have given here.Css i didnt add it here. Check it out the updated code.

Comment: @UrvashiBhatt, Glad to know.

Comment: one problem occur here actually i m using ng-repeat on my <tr> so this event effect on my all textboxes

Comment: @UrvashiBhatt, change the ng-model for textbox. It should be unique. If the ng-model is same . It might have affect other text box as well.

Comment: you are true but my textbox are also repeating in <tr>

Comment: Ok. Try making some fiddle. Difficult for me to point out specifically.